# Removing 1st char from the strings

Tags: shell

I have a file name abc.TXT. The contents of the file are

```
./pub/index.html
./manifest.bak
./manifest.rel
./ns/GSCT_ASNShipmentInfo_E1/node.idf
./ns/GSCT_ASNShipmentInfo_E1/E1/svcUpdateVR01ForOP/flow.xml.bak
./ns/GSCT_ASNShipmentInfo_E1/E1/svcUpdateVR01ForOP/node.ndf
./ns/GSCT_ASNShipmentInfo_E1/E1/svcUpdateVR01ForOP/flow.xml
```

I want to remove the .(dot) from each line and save the content to a new file bcd.TXT.
The content in bcd.TXT should be

```
  /pub/index.html
  /manifest.bak
  /manifest.rel
  /ns/GSCT_ASNShipmentInfo_E1/node.idf
  /ns/GSCT_ASNShipmentInfo_E1/E1/svcUpdateVR01ForOP/flow.xml.bak
  /ns/GSCT_ASNShipmentInfo_E1/E1/svcUpdateVR01ForOP/node.ndf
  /ns/GSCT_ASNShipmentInfo_E1/E1/svcUpdateVR01ForOP/flow.xml
```

Comment: the content in file bcd.TXT should be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/.//' abc.TXT > bcd.TXT
$ cat bcd.TXT
/pub/index.html
/manifest.bak
/manifest.rel
/ns/GSCT_ASNShipmentInfo_E1/node.idf
/ns/GSCT_ASNShipmentInfo_E1/E1/svcUpdateVR01ForOP/flow.xml.bak
/ns/GSCT_ASNShipmentInfo_E1/E1/svcUpdateVR01ForOP/node.ndf
/ns/GSCT_ASNShipmentInfo_E1/E1/svcUpdateVR01ForOP/flow.xml
```

`sed s/.//` replaces a character with nothing once every line. That is, it removes the first character.

Comment: Thank You So Much fedorqui !

Comment: Now I see you probably wanted an approach of removing 1st char... if it was a dot. Well, my answer was based on the sample input and title. In case of need to just delete the dot in the beginning of the line, do escape it: `sed 's/\.//' abc.TXT > bcd.TXT`

Comment: Errr I added my comment for completeness, no need to un-accept jaypal's answer!

Answer (score 1):

[fedorqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21910650/970195)'s answer will remove any first character. So if you are not sure if it is a `.` then you can tell `sed` to remove only if you see a `.`

**Using:**

```
sed 's/^\.//' abc.TXT > bcd.TXT
```

tells `sed` that if first character of my file (denoted with `^`) is a literal `.` (denoted with `\.`), then replace it with nothing.

If you want to make changes in your existing file you can use `-i` option. This will make the changes in your file.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk

```
awk '{sub(/^\./,X)}1' abc.TXT > bcd.TXT
```

Answer (score 0):

Using perl:

```
perl -pe 's/\.//' abc.TXT > bcd.TXT
```

For in place replacement:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\.//' abc.TXT
```